# Two independent events become dependent conditional on a third

Tags: probability

I have consulted the following post, but am still having difficulty understanding this situation:
[Is it possible that two independent variables become dependent conditioning on a third random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900375/is-it-possible-that-two-independent-variables-become-dependent-conditioning-on-a)

If X and Y are independent events but become dependent conditioned on Z, what would the standard notation of this situation look like? Also, what would an actual example of this be in real life?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I understand your question, take a regular game dice. $X=1$ if the dice is set on $1$ or $2$. $Y = 1$ if the dice is set on an even number. Both of them are $0$ otherwise. They are independent. Now take $Z$ to be indicator if the dice is set on $1$, and $0$ otherwise. Is it a good example for what you looking?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this example during a course in probabilistic learning. The idea around this concept is pretty simple and its better to use an example to illustrate it.

Suppose $R$ denotes the event that it rains, and $S$ denotes the event that the sprinklers turn on.

Now, we know that whether or not the sprinklers turn on is  independent of whether or not it rains, so we are in the situation of having two independent random variables.

Say one morning, you wake up and realise that the ground outside is wet (Label this event as $W$). Now, conditioning on this event (wet ground), $R$ and $S$ are not independent anymore, since you know that at least one of $R$ or $S$ must have occurred. In other words, if the ground is wet, and I tell you that it did not rain, then you would know that the sprinklers were turned on.

To make this concrete, say we have:

$$
Pr(R) = 0.5\\
Pr(S) = 0.5\\
Pr(W) = 0.8\\
$$
Note that:

$$
Pr(W|R) = 1\\
Pr(W|S) = 1
$$
i.e. if it rains or if the sprinklers turn on you can be sure that the ground is wet.

So this gives us (via Bayes):
$$
Pr(R|W) = \frac{Pr(W|R)Pr(R)}{Pr(W)} = \frac{5}{8}
$$
and
$$
Pr(S|W) = \frac{Pr(W|S)Pr(S)}{Pr(W)} = \frac{5}{8}
$$

Now, if we had conditional independence, it would imply that:
$$
Pr(S,R|W) = Pr(S|W)Pr(R|W) = \frac{5^2}{8^2} = \frac{25}{64}
$$
But by the laws of conditional probability:
$$
\begin{align}
Pr(S,R|W) &= Pr(S|R,W)Pr(R|W)\\
&=Pr(S|R)\frac{5}{8} \\
&=\frac{5}{16}
\end{align}
$$
Which is a contradiction.

Note: the second equality follows from observing that the floor is wet when it rains, hence we can take remove $W$ from the conditional probability to obtain $Pr(S|R)$.

Answer (score 0):

? If X and Y are independent events but become dependent conditioned on Z, what would the standard notation of this situation look like?

$X\perp Y$ and yet $X\not\perp Y\mid Z$

Example: $X$ is the count for heads on the first of two independent fair coin tosses, $Y$ is the count for heads on the second, and $Z$ is the count for heads among both tosses.   $X\perp Y$ as the results are from independent tosses.   $X\not\perp Y\mid Z$ as the results are not (conditionally)independent when given the count of heads among both tosses (knowing the result of one toss would then determine the result of the other).